# datetime-local auto-fill Date() UTC with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, datetime

Having issue auto-fill of form-field datetime-local, with button calling function of Javascript Date() method to .value in HTML5 form.

I have tested multiple formats and can auto-fill text field with ISO datetime but not datetime-local?

Desire to have (for ease of UI) a button to side of field for auto-fill of current locale time (client side) into standard Chrome date-time local format in addition to Chrome browser datetime picker for desktop clients. In mobile clients the webkit is calling native datetime picker with now button built in.

NOTE: I am aware that this form data type is not available in all browsers and will probably be deprecated. However application users will be using chrome mobile and desktop as recommended browser ('Viewed best in...') for most consistency across hardware.

Code follows:

```
<p>
<label>Date</label><br> 
<input type="datetime-local" id='my_date' name='my_date' required/>
<button type="button" id='btn_date_now' name='btn_date_now' onClick="get_now_datetime();" >Now</button>
</p>

<script>
function get_now_datetime()
{
var myField = document.getElementById("my_date");
var D = new Date();
myField.value = D.toISOString();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use valueAsDate or valueAsNumber.  Try the following code.

```
function get_now_datetime()
{
    var myField = document.getElementById("my_date");
    var now = new Date();
    myField.valueAsNumber = now.getTime() - now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
}
```